# Is there any environment that implements the new custom elements specification?

Tags: javascript, custom-element

A new version of the custom elements has been released at some point in the past (not sure when, as I haven't directly used the spec for awhile). Is there any polyfill or environment that implements the new custom elements specification?

Reason I am asking is that I will be giving a talk on Friday about the web components specs and it will hardly do to give a talk without a demonstrations, but from what I can see all browsers and polyfills still implement the old spec. Looking at web archive I can see that the new spec has been around for at least a few months, so I would expect it to be implemented at least somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2020 Update**: now it runs in Chrome, Opera and Edge (Blink), Firefox (Gecko), and partially on Safari (WebKit).

Otherwise you can use a polyfill from [WebReflection](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) for IE11 / Firefox / Chrome.

Presentation of what has changed [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/179IRXRFmDGb3P60OVsoAIsElcaOp__5EuIWLcL8oNos/edit#slide=id.p).

---

The [**Custom Elements v1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) Specification is available since Chrome v53. It's a native implementation.

*Note:* You have to run it with a flag to activate the feature:

```
> chrome --enable-blink-features=CustomElementsV1
```

You can add the flag in your shortcut if you want.

*PS:* I recommend to use the last build ([Canary](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)) because the implementation is being updated on a regular basis.

---

**Running Example :**

```js
class CEv1 extends HTMLElement 
{
  constructor () 
  {
    super()
    console.log( "created this=", this )            
  }
  
  connectedCallback ()
  {
    this.innerHTML = "Hello V1!"
  }
} 
customElements.define( "test-v1", CEv1 )
```

```html
<test-v1>Feature not activated</test-v1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually did check both Canary and the Firefox nightlies, but I didn't think about checking for flags or anything along those lines.