# Why does `color` affect shadow roots?

Tags: css, shadow-dom

I noticed that when I do the following ([note: this is Shadow DOM v1!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723962/is-there-any-environment-that-implements-the-new-custom-elements-specification))

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let root = div.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = 'Super hot!';
root.appendChild(span);
```

```css
*{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The `color` property is propagated in to the shadow root, whilst the `background` property is not. Which part of the specification defines this behavior and why is this? I was under the impression that shadow roots were primarily meant for the encapsulation of DOM trees.

Screenshot of the above snippet:

[image]

Screenshot of the above snippet without the `background` and with just `color: green`

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot of how this looks? I’m super curious but can’t be bothered to get Chrome to run this ^^"

Comment: @poke: Added. And here is a screenshot of the answer by Supersharp http://imgur.com/a/QYl7J

Answer (score 1):

It's an optical illusion, due to the use of `*` and opacity.

The `span` didn't inherit from the *span CSS* rule, the *color* and *background* are propagated from the `div` element under the shadow.

See code below with distinct colors. Inspect the *Styles* properties with Chrome Dev Tool to see the ones that apply.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let root = div.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'})
let span = document.createElement('span')
span.textContent = "Text in the SPAN, but colors from DIV"
root.appendChild(span)
```

```css
div {
  /*background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.1);*/
  color: green;
}
span {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.2);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h4>SPAN in Shadow DOM:</h4>
<div id="v1">Text and colors from DIV</div>

<h4>No Shadow DOM:</h4>
<div>Text and colors from DIV<span>Text and colors from SPAN</span></div>
```

**Update**: As @poke stated:

> The shadow DOM only shuts off the CSS rules but not the inheritance that happens in the document.

That's why the name "Shadow" is expressive and meaningfull.

What you experienced with the background is also true for normal CSS and DOMs (not related to Shadow DOM encapsulation).

Comment: Try setting the color to green and remove the background ;)

Comment: Possibly I might be misunderstanding the shadow dom, why does the color of the `div` affect the `span` in the first case? Because you're seeing 'Text in the SPAN' line in green as well?

Comment: The color, like many other properties like `font`, is inherited. That makes the text of the span have the same color as the div that contains the shadow DOM. Now, backgrounds are not inherited by default but is transparent by default. So the span’s background is transparent which makes the span not have a background on its own. The shadow DOM only shuts off the CSS *rules* but not the inheritance that happens in the document. Otherwise, you wouldn’t be able to change a component’s font for example without specifying it for each one individually.