# Can I have slotted Shadow DOM content if I have an intermediate element in between?

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

Going through the Shadow DOM (v1) example [in this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom), it defines a Web Component (tabs), wherein each Tab corresponds to a named and default slot:

```
<fancy-tabs>
  <button slot="title">Title</button>
  <button slot="title" selected>Title 2</button>
  <button slot="title">Title 3</button>
  <section>content panel 1</section>
  <section>content panel 2</section>
  <section>content panel 3</section>
</fancy-tabs>
```

And it would render to this:

```
<fancy-tabs>
  #shadow-root
    <div id="tabs">
      <slot id="tabsSlot" name="title">
        <button slot="title">Title</button>
        <button slot="title" selected>Title 2</button>
        <button slot="title">Title 3</button>
      </slot>
    </div>
    <div id="panels">
      <slot id="panelsSlot">
        <section>content panel 1</section>
        <section>content panel 2</section>
        <section>content panel 3</section>
      </slot>
    </div>
</fancy-tabs>
```

In order to preserve an existing API, I'd like to create a component similar to this, but one where I can create each Tab as its own Custom Element. So an API that looks like:

```
<fancy-tabs>
  <fancy-tab>
    <button slot="title">Title</button>
    <section>content panel 1</section>
  </fancy-tab>
  <fancy-tab>
    <button slot="title" selected>Title 2</button>
    <section>content panel 2</section>
  <fancy-tab>
  <fancy-tab>
    <button slot="title" selected>Title 3</button>
    <section>content panel 3</section>
  <fancy-tab>
</fancy-tabs>
```

But have it render to similar Shadow DOM as above.

In other words, what I'd like is to have is an intermediate element like `<fancy-tab>`, while still controlling the slot elements below it. I've tried creating `<fancy-tab>` as a CE with an open shadowRoot, as a CE with no shadowRoot, and not defining it as a custom element at all.

**Is there a way to do this?** Or do slots *have* to be at the first child of the Light DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with a `slot` attribute have to be first childs of the Light DOM.

So if you want to keep the structure of your 3rd piece of code, you could use [nested custom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38976819/4600982), each with shadow DOM.

The `<fancy-tabs>` component will grab the `<fancy-tab>`.
The `<fancy-tab>` component will grab the content.

---

Actually to create a "tabs" component you don't even have to define sub-components of shadow DOM (but you can for customization needs of course).

Here's a minimal `<fancy-tabs>` custom-element example:

```js
customElements.define( 'fancy-tabs', class extends HTMLElement 
{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
        this.btns = this.querySelectorAll( 'button ')
        this.addEventListener( 'click', this )
        this.querySelector( 'button[selected]' ).focus()
    }

    handleEvent( ev ) 
    {
        this.btns.forEach( b => 
        {
            if ( b === ev.target ) 
                b.setAttribute( 'selected', true )
            else
                b.removeAttribute( 'selected' )
        } )
    }
} )
```

```css
fancy-tabs {
    position: relative ;
}

fancy-tab > button {
    border: none ;
}

fancy-tab > section {
    background: #eee ;
    display: none ;
    position: absolute ; left: 0 ; top: 20px ;
    width: 300px ; height: 75px ;
}

fancy-tab > button[selected] + section {
    display: inline-block  ;
}
```

```html
<fancy-tabs>
    <fancy-tab>
        <button>Title 1</button>
        <section>content panel 1</section>
    </fancy-tab>
    <fancy-tab>
        <button selected>Title 2</button>
        <section>content panel 2</section>
    </fancy-tab>
    <fancy-tab>
        <button>Title 3</button>
        <section>content panel 3</section>
    </fancy-tab>
</fancy-tabs>
```