# Webcomponents Polyfill not working

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, polyfills, html-imports

I am trying to polyfill webcomponents as explained at https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills/ since I wanted my sample app to work on both Chrome and Firefox. However I am getting **ReferenceError: customElements is not defined** error in Firefox. See my code below on the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
    <!-- Components -->
    <link rel="import" href="components/global/site-navigation.html">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        (function () {
            if ('registerElement' in document
                && 'import' in document.createElement('link')
                && 'content' in document.createElement('template')) {
                // platform is good!
            } else {
                // polyfill the platform!
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.src = 'js/webcomponents.js';
                document.body.appendChild(e);
            }
        })();
    </script>
    <site-navigation></site-navigation>
</body>    
</html>
```

What am I missing?

PS: Everything works fine in Chrome (with/without the polyfill)

Comment: I think you need to place your polyfill loader code _before_ you include you components.

Comment: what version of webcomponents polyfill do you use?

Comment: I can see this in line:10 of webcomponents.js // @version 0.7.24

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an old version of **webcomponentsjs** polyfill,  which implements Custom Elements v0's `document.registerElement()` instead of v1's `customElements.define()`.

You should use the new [version 1.0 on github](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs).

Just load the *webomponents-lite.js* script in the `<head>` part of your page:

```
<script src="webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

---

**Update**: Now polyfill version 2 was released. HTML Imports polyfill is not shipped any more, but can be used it separately, or you can still download **v1 branch**.

Comment: This worked but I have a new issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233481/attached-shadowroot-using-polyfill-is-not-query-able. Meantime, do you have a working sample of vanilla webcomponents anywhere?

Comment: You can find some exampes on SO i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38990195/4600982

Comment: @MaheshVS you can check this out: https://ayushgp.github.io/html-web-components-using-vanilla-js