# The second angular element (custom element) is not displayed

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element, angular-elements

I have two Angular Elements.
The first one contains select-box and the second one looks like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I try to display both inside another application using @angular-extensions/elements or just by adding script to index.html:

It works:

```
<app-select *axLazyElement="'assets/select.js'"></app-select>
```

And it works:

```
<app-dashboard *axLazyElement="'assets/dashboard.js'">some text</app-dashboard>
```

It displays only select:

```
<app-select *axLazyElement="'assets/select.js'"></app-select>

<app-dashboard *axLazyElement="'assets/dashboard.js'">
    <div>some text
        <app-select *axLazyElement="'assets/select.js'"></app-select>
    </div>
</app-dashboard>
```

And this two display only dashboard without select inside:

```
<app-dashboard *axLazyElement="'assets/dashboard.js'">
    <div>some text
        <app-select *axLazyElement="'assets/select.js'"></app-select>
    </div>
</app-dashboard>
```

```
<app-dashboard *axLazyElement="'assets/dashboard.js'">
    <div>some text</div>
</app-dashboard>

<app-select *axLazyElement="'assets/select.js'"></app-select>
```

I always see only first custom element.
I see that both scripts loaded in browser network and i do not see any errors in console.
Does anybody know what happens?

Comment: First step is to use F12 Dev Tools to explore what HTML is created, and check with the author of the component what notation is required

Comment: I'm the author of both components. I see <-- ng-reflect-if: path/to/element --> 
and than nothing

Comment: Then the problem is in your Elements code, not with the HTML usage code you show us above

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this Ivan. I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Your're using nested components. Isn't it the the lack of adding the nested elements inside your web component? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976819/composing-v1-nested-web-components