# Using :host-context() with an adjacent sibling selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, web-component

I'm trying to use :host-context() and adjacent sibling selectors to style an element like this:

```
<x-foo id="1" active></x-foo>
<x-foo id="2"></x-foo> <!-- use :host-context() to target #2 when adjacent sibling, #1 is [active] -->
<x-foo id="3"></x-foo>
```

My element definition looks something like:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
        <style>
           :host-context(x-foo[active] + x-foo) {
               background-color: yellow;
           }
        </style>
        Hello
    </template>
    <script src="x-foo.js"></script>    
</dom-module>
```

However this doesn't quite work. Why not?

Comment: `:host-context(...):host` is redundant - `:host` has a functional form `:host(...)` for when you only want to match the host element against the selector argument.

Comment: Yeah, that was just cruft I forgot to trim from my demo. Fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`:host()` and `:host-context()` only accept a compound selector as their argument](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector), and not a complex selector.

`x-foo[active] + x-foo` is a complex selector that contains two compound selectors, `x-foo[active]` and `x-foo`, separated by the adjacent sibling combinator. `:host()` and `:host-context()` can accept either compound selector, but not any combinators.

Unfortunately, because the shadow host's siblings do not exist in the shadow context, you won't be able to write something like `x-foo[active] + :host`. As a consequence, I don't think you will be able to accomplish what you're looking to do in a shadow context. (In the light context, of course, you can just write `x-foo[active] + x-foo`, but that defeats the purpose of prepackaging CSS into a web component.)

It's not clear to me why `:host()` and `:host-context()` weren't specced to allow complex selectors in the first place, since if they did, what you have would have just worked.

Comment: In a shadow context you can also just write `x-foo[active] + x-foo`, because the `background-color` in inherited from its parent.

Comment: @Supersharp: x-foo is the shadow host in this context. You cannot match the shadow host with anything but the :host pseudos in a shadow context. And backgrounds aren't inherited - they just show through when the child element is transparent. (An *alarming* number of people seem to think backgrounds are inherited for some reason, and I can't tell if it's because those people misunderstand the word "inheritance", or if those people have forgotten what a background is and how it works.)

Comment: Thanks -- I was afraid this was the case.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround would be to add a global `<style>` rule.

You add it when you want (in the `attachedCallback/connectedCallback` for example). In the above snippet I put the `<style>` tag in the `<template>` of the custom element, and I move it once `x-foo` is defined.

```js
customElements.define( 'x-foo', class XFoo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open'} )
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild( tpl.content.cloneNode( true ) )
  }
} )

customElements.whenDefined( 'x-foo' ).then( () =>
  document.head.appendChild( tpl.content.getElementById( 'global' ) )
)
```

```html
<x-foo id="1" active></x-foo>
<x-foo id="2"></x-foo>
<x-foo id="3"></x-foo>

<!-- custom element v1 -->
<template id="tpl">
  <style id="global">
    x-foo[active] + x-foo { background: yellow ; color: red }
  </style>

  <style>
    :host { background: lightblue ; display: inline-block }
    span { color: initial }
  </style>

  <span>Hello</span>
</template>
```

*Note*: I have used a custom element (v1) instead of Polymer, it works in [Chrome v53+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38723962/4600982).

Comment: I appreciate the effort but this is a hack

Comment: Every answer in SO is a hack... otherwise it's because someone didn't RTFM