# Webcomponents: Adjacent sibling selectors in children

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component

How can you target the following in Webcomponents? (ShadomDom V1 & Custom Elements V1)

```
pagination-item + pagination-item {
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

in the following...

```
<pagination>
    <pagination-item></pagination-item>
    <pagination-item></pagination-item>
</pagination>
```

If I put it inside the pagination element style, it does not work. If I put `:host + :host` inside the pagination-item, it does not work.

How can you achieve this without hacks? 
If you can't it seems like this is a huge problem in composability...

Comment: Might [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992081/using-host-context-with-an-adjacent-sibling-selector) be the same problem as the one you describe? If so, I agree with your last statement.

Answer (score 1):

It should work by default (didn't you mean margin-*left*?).

If not you can use `:not(:first-child)` in the container (if it's also a Shadow DOM):

```
::slotted(pagination-item:not(:first-child)) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Or you can use it in the `<position-item>` element:

```
:host(:not(:first-child)) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

---

*Note* : Selectors in `::slotted` pseudo elements are restricted to counpound selectors for [performance concerns](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#v1_8):

> While `::content` can take any arbitrary selector, `::slotted` can only take a compound selector (in the parenthesis). The reason of this restriction is to make a selector style-engine friendly, in terms of performance. In v0, it is difficult to avoid a performance penalty caused by an arbitrary selector which crosses shadow boundaries.

Comment: I guess that works too. Why margin-right: inherit though?

Comment: @BoltClock because... I don't know! -> removed