# How to access light dom of custom element inside a slot?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

So, basically I have a `ui-button` that is a molecule. This element is composed with `ui-text` and `ui-icon` elements that are atoms. I want apply a `margin-left` to the text when the button has an icon.

However, the text is a `span` element inside the shadow dom of `ui-text`. That means that inside `ui-button` I have a nested shadow dom corresponding to `ui-text`:

```
<ui-button kind="primary" useForClick="someFn">
  <ui-icon name="payment"></ui-icon>
  <ui-text>Pay with card</ui-text>
<ui-button>
```

Rendered:

```
ui-button
|__shadow dom
   |__ui-icon
   |__ui-text
      |__shadow dom
         |__span
```

How can I access to the inner shadow dom from parent element via CSS? The idea is apply something like this inside `ui-button`:

```
slot[name=text]::slotted(ui-text) span::slotted() {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: did you try something like `ui-icon + ui-text { margin-left: 10px }` inside the ui-button Shadow DOM?

Comment: @Supersharp thanks for reply. In fact, if the `ui-text` is placed directly inside the `ui-button` instead of a `slot`, it works. Otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would use `::slotted( ui-icon + ui-text ) { margin-left: 10px }` in the `<ui-button>` Shadow DOM in order to add a left margin to a `<ui-text>` element following a `<ui-icon>` element.

Actually il not possible because `::slotted()` allow only compound selector, not complex ones constructed with `+`, `>`, `~` and   (space). You'll have to find a workaround depending on your need.

In the example above you can use the `:first-child` pseudo-class combined with `:not()` pseudo-class function.

```
::slotted( :not(:first-child) ) {
    left-margin: 10px 
}
```

You can read also [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41306937/4600982) for an alternate solution with `:host()`.