# How to create new instance of an extended class of custom elements

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying the example from [google developer site](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements#extendhtml) and I'm getting Error: "TypeError: Illegal constructor.
What's wrong and How to fix it?

```
class FancyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
  constructor() {
    super(); // always call super() first in the ctor.
    this.addEventListener('click', e => this.drawRipple(e.offsetX,e.offsetY));
  }

  // Material design ripple animation.
  drawRipple(x, y) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('ripple');
    this.appendChild(div);
    //    div.style.top = `${y - div.clientHeight/2}px`;
    //    div.style.left = `${x - div.clientWidth/2}px`;
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'currentColor';
    div.classList.add('run');
    div.addEventListener('transitionend', e => div.remove());
  }
}

customElements.define('fancy-button', FancyButton, {extends: 'button'});
let button = new FancyButton();
button.textContent = 'Fancy button!';
button.disabled = true;
```

Comment: What browser (version) are you using?

Comment: None of the current browsers supports [Custom Elements v1](http://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1).

Comment: From the developer site: Chrome 54 (status) has Custom Elements v1. Safari has begun prototyping and you can test the API in WebKit nightly. Edge has begun prototyping. Mozilla has an open bug to implement.

Comment: Safari won't implement customized built-in elements in a first time AFAIK

Answer (score 16):

Blink, the web engine that currently implements Custom Element v1 (in [Chrome v53+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38725765/4600982) for example) only supports [*autonomous custom elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements-autonomous-example): see open [Blink bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=648828).

If you want to define [*customized built-in elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements-customized-builtin-example) (i.e. `<button>` extension), you'll need to use a polyfill like [the one from Web Reflection](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element).

Alternatly, you can still use the Custom Element v0 syntax (`document.registerElement`).

---

**Update #3**

Since october 2018, they work natively with Chrome 67+ and Firefox 63+ :-)

Comment: Also, check https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1 for updated compatibility table

Answer (score 6):

```
class F_BTN extends HTMLButtonElement{
    constructor(){
        super(); // must call constructor from parent class
        this.addEventListener(...);
        .... // etc.
     }
}

customElements.define("f-btn",F_BTN,{extends:'button'});
```

use inline:

```
<body>  ....  <f-btn>BTN_NAME</f-btn>  ...  </body>
```

or create append from javascript

```
var elm = new F_BTN(...options); 
// F_BTN = customElements.get('f-btn') // in case F_BTN is out of scope
```

**The problem** is `elm = document.createElement('f-btn')` doesn't work.

That is why I made my custom create_element function **_E**

```
_E = function (name, html) {
  var $;
  switch (true) {
    case (name === '' || !name):  // _E()  -- a div
        {
            $ = document.createElement('div');
        }
        break; 
    case (!name.indexOf('<')):  // _E('<h1><i>abc</i><b>A</b></h1>')  -- sub_dom
        {
            $ = document.createElement('div');
            $.innerHTML = name;
            $ = $.firstElementChild;
        }
        break;
    default:
        var c = window.customElements.get(name);
        if(c){ 
          $ = new c();   // _E('f-btn')  -- customElement
        } else {
          $ = document.createElement(name); // _E('button')  -- htmlElement
        }   
  }      
  if (html) $.innerHTML = html;
  return $;
};

var elm1 = _E('f-btn'); parent.appendChild(elm1);
```

Comment: Adding the `extends` option in the the `customElements.define` method worked for me. Thanks.