# Unable to create custom element when extending built-in element in Chrome 54

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-component, custom-element

I'm unable to create a custom element when extending from a built-in element in Chrome 54.

To my knowledge this feature has [shipped](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/nic54). Is there something I am missing? Perhaps this portion of the v1 spec is still in flux.

```
<super-element>Super Element</super-element>
<button is="super-button">Super Button</button>

<script>
    customElements.define('super-element', class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            console.log('Super Element');
        }
    });  

    customElements.define('super-button', class extends HTMLButtonElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            console.log('Super Button');
        }
    }, {extends: 'button'});       
</script>

// Output: Super Element
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: No errors. Just the "Super Element" output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps this portion of the v1 spec is still in flux.

Exactely.

*Customized built-in* elements are not implemented yet in Blink, the Chrome & Opera HTML rendering engine.

Look at the ["Launch"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=652579) and ["Implement"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=648828) bugs in Chromium project's tracker.

See also SO answer [here for a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39986046/4600982).

**Update with Chrome 67**

Now it works with versions of Chrome version 67 and above.