# Customized built-in elements do not work in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, web-component, native-web-component

## The problem

This [autonomous custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) works both in the content.js(extension JavaScript context) and top JavaScript context:

```
window.customElements.get('custom-element') || customElements.define('custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('custom-element constructed');
  }
  
  connectedCallback(){
    console.log('custom-element connected');
  }
});

let ce = document.createElement('div')
ce.innerHTML = `<custom-element name="my-element">`
document.body.appendChild(ce)
```

But this customized built-in element does not work in the extension JavaScript context, though it works in the top JavaScript context.

```
window.customElements.get('custom-builtin-element') || customElements.define('custom-builtin-element', class extends HTMLInputElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('custom-builtin-element constructed');
  }
  
  connectedCallback(){
    console.log('custom-builtin-element connected');
  }
}, {extends: 'input'});

let cbie = document.createElement('div')
cbie.innerHTML = `<input is='custom-builtin-element' type="radio">`
document.body.appendChild(cbie)
```

## Settings and tried

Here is the related part in manifest.json:

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "webcomponents-sd-ce.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The `webcomponents-sd-ce.js` is added according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45425370/3552975). And I also tried [`webcomponents-bundle.js`](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs).

My Chrome is the latest [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320770/3552975): `Version 119.0.6045.123`.

---

(How) can I use the customized built-in element in a Chrome extension's content.js?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an architectural limitation of content scripts, see https://crbug.com/390807. Either don't use custom elements at all or put your content script into the unsafe MAIN world where it's not protected from potential prototype poisoning/spoofing.

Comment: @wOxxOm So, it's possible to tackle this problem, right? Given the potential risks, I will try to avoid using custom elements. Thanks.

Comment: Apple has not changed their POV since 2016; they will not implement _Customized Built-In Elements_. So be aware you are gathering knowledge which only works in the Chromium and FireFox domain.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks! You are right. I should do some research into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [main concern](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390807) is namespace collision:

> > it IS actually impossible
>
> If the extension goes first, the page will break. If the page goes
> first, the extension will break.
>
> > up to us extension devs
>
> Some devs are great. Others are not necessarily aware of the
> consequences of some piece of code, and its our job (the platform
> developers) to mitigate that as much as possible.
>
> Like I said whether or not it's up to devs, we've seen it happen,
> users complain to website owner that website doesn't work, website
> owner looks into it, finds extension, and eventually - blames us.
> Maybe we go and blame extension but, wow, does that all take a long
> time.
>
> > security issue
>
> I don't think so, no more than DOM manipulation. JS code stays
> sandboxed.

---

Just a tried and true walk-round(thanks to this repo: [ungap/custom-elements](https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements)):
Download [this min.js file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ungap/custom-elements/master/min.js) into your project and include it in your content_scripts.

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "webcomponents-sd-ce.js",
        "min.js",
        "content.js"
        
      ]
    }
  ]
```

---

But as mentioned in the comments, the best practice is to avoid using custom elements in content.js at all.