# How to extend <form> using Custom Elements v1 in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I've tried to define a new custom element extends HTMLFormElement like:

```
class PrintableFormElement extends HTMLFormElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("created: ", this);
  }
  print() { console.log(this.elements)); }
}
customElements.define("printable-form", PrintableFormElement, { extends: "form" });
```

This doesn't work right. `<form is="printable-form" ...>` doesn't have the `print()` method (`define(...)` seems to be failed), and `new PrintableFormElement` are fail with an error with Google Chrome 55.

`new PrintableFormElement` threw the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
    at PrintableFormElement (<anonymous>:3:5)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I have no idea how to define a custom element extends  with Custom Elements v1 in current Google Chrome.

Custom Elements v0 works well but I want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customized Built-in Elements "v1" are not implemented yet in Chrome, you should use
a polyfill.

For more details, see also this question from SO:

- [How to create new instance of an extended class of custom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39986046/4600982)