# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor when extending HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I have the following class from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements):

```
class FancyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
    constructor() {
        super(); // always call super() first in the ctor.
        this.addEventListener('click', e => this.drawRipple(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
    }

    // Material design ripple animation.
    drawRipple(x, y) {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('ripple');
        this.appendChild(div);
        div.style.top = `${y - div.clientHeight / 2}px`;
        div.style.left = `${x - div.clientWidth / 2}px`;
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'currentColor';
        div.classList.add('run');
        div.addEventListener('transitionend', e => div.remove());
    }
}
```

When it's being instantiated, I get the error:

```
fancy-button.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

When I click on the location, I'm presented with this:

```
((e) => { throw e; })
```

What's wrong with the class constructor?

Comment: It's not implemented yet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39986046/4600982