# HTML5 ES6 Custom-Elements extending HTMLTextAreaElement crashes illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ecmascript-6, custom-element

i need to extend a custom element from HTMLTextAreaElement for using in a form and fetch value directly. but i allways get Illegal Constructor Message

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <working-element></working-element>
    </div>
    <div>
      <crashing-element></crashing-element>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="myScript.js">
</html>
```

Typescript (compiled as ES6 to myScript.js):

```
// all works fine
class newElementWorks extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    console.log('newElementWorks');
  }
}
customElements.define('working-element', newElementWorks);

// this one crashes on super() call
class newElementCrash extends HTMLTextAreaElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    console.log('newElementCrash');
  }
}
customElements.define('crashing-element', newElementCrash);
```

the script is executed on Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 that supports ES6 and Custom-Element

i allready tried to include [webcomponents/custom-elements](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements) polyfill

do you have any idea why extending from other than HTMLElement crashes?

Comment: Do you transpile the TypeScript code to ES5 or ES6?

Comment: @Bergi : to ES6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create new instance of an extended class of custom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986046/how-to-create-new-instance-of-an-extended-class-of-custom-elements)

Answer (score 6):

The error you are seeing means that the object you are calling `new` on does not have a `[[construct]]` internal method.

Although the specs indicates that you can `extend` HTML*Element classes it does not seem to be supported at this time ( see a similar issue : https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements/issues/6 ) so you can only extend `HTMLElement`at this moment.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. im wondering why there are so many tutorials online where extanding from HTML*Element is done if it does not work in any browser.

Comment: Do they polyfill those classes ? If you have a link to one of those I'll look into it as there is not enough information to be sure of what the problem is. The only conclusion you can  come at this moment is that `HTML*Element` cannot be inherited from.

Comment: no, they dont support other than HTMLElement. The answer to the issue i opened is : I will come soon.

Comment: This is my conclusion in my answer, is it ok for you to accept it or do you find it lacking in some way (for future readership proofing) ?

Answer (score 2):

Two things are blatantly wrong in your attempt at extending `HTMLTextAreaElement`.

1. You **must** add the mandatory `{ extends: 'textarea' }` third argument when registering your element.
2. Extended built-in-elements don't get a tag of their own, instead use the tag of the extended element, adding your name in an `is=""` attribute.

```js
class MyTextarea extends HTMLTextAreaElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    console.log('MyTextarea');
  }
}

customElements.define('my-textarea', MyTextarea, {extends: 'textarea'});
```

```html
<textarea is="my-textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Nice, And how can I create `my-textarea` via JS only? or give no textual data to the element in the construction time?

Comment: @perymimon `document.createElement('textarea', { is: 'my-textarea' })`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement